# Was General Products named after General Dynamics?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, known-space

As I was recently rereading "Neutron Star"* by Larry Niven, I was struck by the way the impregnable General Products hulls were described.

> The ship lay on the sand beyond the roof.  It was a No. 2 General Products hull:  a cylinder three hundred feet long and twenty feet through, pointed at both ends and with a slight wasp-waist constriction near the tail.  For some reason it was lying on its side, with the landing shocks still folded in at the tail.
>
> Ever notice how all ships have begun to look the same?  A good ninety-five percent of today’s spacecraft are built around one of the four General Products hulls.  It’s easier and safer to build that way, but somehow all ships end as they began: mass-produced look-alikes.

They sound very submarine like.  (Science fiction spaceships build like submarines was, of course, nothing new.  The Thing's spacecraft in ["Who Goes There"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Goes_There%3F) was likened to a sub, before it was accidentally detonated.)  This caught my attention, since I also noticed the similarity of the name "General Products" to "General Dynamics."  General Dynamics is a major American defense contractor and, specifically, the builder of the U. S. Navy's nuclear-powered submarines, through their [Electric Boat](http://www.gdeb.com/suppliers/) division in Groton, Connecticut.  This raised a natural question in my mind, which simple Web searches have not answered:  Was Niven thinking of the "General Dynamics" name when he created the Puppeteer's General Products corporation?

*When Niven wrote the story in 1966, he predicted that it would require faster-than-light travel and exploration and colonization of a larger region of space to discover a single neutron star.  The first neutron stars were actually discovered by [Jocelyn Bell Burnell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocelyn_Bell_Burnell) in 1967, based on their radio signatures as pulsars.

Comment: You're way over thinking this. GENERAL X is a common name in US companies.

Comment: @Paulie_D As a matter of fact, General Electric was a much better known company in the late 1960s than General Dynamics.

Comment: General Atomics, General Foods, General Mills, General Motors, the list goes on.

Comment: There are four types of GP hulls.  Only one looks anything like a submarine.

Comment: General Robotics...